# Days Until Birthday is not Calculated Correctly (Java)

Tags: java

I was developing this java program that tells the user the number of days in their birth month and the number of days until their birthday, the former part works and the number of days until their birthday works if it's less than three months away but I can't figure out why it doesn't work after that point

```
import java.util.*;
public class Jack_Dennin_HW2
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("What month of the year is it?(1-12)");
      int month = (sc.nextInt()-1);
      System.out.println("What day of the month?");
      int day = sc.nextInt();
      System.out.println("What month is your birthday?(1-12)");
      int bmonth = (sc.nextInt()-1);
      System.out.println("What day of that month is your birthday?");
      int bday = sc.nextInt();
      Date today = new Date(month, day);
      Date birthday = new Date(bmonth, bday);
      int sum = (today.daysInMonth()-day+bday);
      System.out.println("There are "+birthday.daysInMonth()+" days in your birth month");
      if (month==bmonth)
      {
         if(day==bday)
         {
            System.out.println("Happy Birthday!");
         }
         else if(bday>day)
         {
            System.out.println("Your birthday is "+(bday-day)+" days away");
         }
         else
         {
            System.out.println("Your birthday is "+(365+bday-day)+" days away");
         }
      }
      else
      {

         for(int i = month+1; i==(bmonth-1)%12; i++)
         {
            Date n = new Date(i%12,1);
            sum=(sum+n.daysInMonth());
         }
         System.out.println("There are "+sum+" days until your birthday");        
      }
   }
}
class Date
{
   private int month;
   private int day;
   public Date(int month2, int day2)
   {
      month = month2;
      day = day2;
   }
   public int getMonth()
   {
      return(month);
   }
   public int getDay()
   {
      return(day);
   }
   public String toString()
   {
      String day2;
      if (day%10==day)
      {
         day2 = "0"+day;
      }
      else
      {
         day2 = day+"";
      }
      return(month+"/"+day2);
   }
   public int daysInMonth()
   {
      switch(month)
      {
         case 0: return(31);
         case 1: return(28);
         case 2: return(31);
         case 3: return(30);
         case 4: return(31);
         case 5: return(30);
         case 6: return(31);
         case 7: return(31);
         case 8: return(30);
         case 9: return(31);
         case 10: return(30);
         case 11: return(31);
         default: return(-1);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/33293572/10316073

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of this line:

```
for(int i = month+1; i==(bmonth-1)%12; i++)
```

Specifically, `i==(bmonth-1)%12`.

Lets take two dates: 1st of January and 1st of February. In that case, `month=0`, `i=0+1=1`, `i==1%12` is true, and you drop into the for statement and calculate the days correctly.

Lets take another two dates: 1st of January and 1st of April. In that case, `month=0`, `i=1`, but `i==2%12` is false, so you do not drop into the for statement and therefore do not calculate the correct sum.

Since this is homework, I will not tell you the solution, but the line that needs to be fixed is `i==(bmonth-1)%12`. Its a very simple fix.

P.S. Take some time to learn how to use a debugger! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but are you sure this is simple? I've been looking at this for 40 minutes and haven't figured it out.

Comment: Yes, it's changing the == operator to something else ;)

Comment: @SaucySpirit figured it out or still need help?